# How can I install Hjelmslund USB485 in debian

Tags: linux, rs485

As the title says!

I can read info from the device with "dmesg" and see it when "lsusb" but how do I attach/install it as for example dev/ttyUSB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to change the VID and PID with FTDI software FT Prog (utility for programming the EEPROM of FTxxx devices). Change to 0403 and 6001, Linux will then recognise it as a generic FTDI.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the ftdi chips settings, you could just add the VID / PID to the list of ids recognized by the ftdi driver. To do this at run time (non permanent) do:

```
modprobe ftdi_sio
echo "1c40 0477" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
```